# What is this "/\,$/"?

Tags: javascript

Tried to search for `/\,$/` online, but coudnt find anything. 
I have:

```
coords = coords.replace(/\,$/, "");
```

Im guessing it returns coords string index number. What I have to search online for this, so I can learn more?

Comment: That's a regex literal.

Comment: You'll get used to regex. It will confuse you largely but it is a very useful tool when you need it. In time, you will become a REGEXPERT! Sorry that was idiotic.

Answer (score 2):

`/\,$/` finds the comma character (`,`) at the end of a string (denoted by the `$`) and replaces it with empty (`""`). You sometimes see this in regex code aiming to clean up excerpts of text.

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular expression to remove a trailing comma.

Comment: The last comma is what I mean by "trailing comma"

Comment: He means that you said comma(s) - plural. /pedantry

Comment: Yeah seems minor, but it is important to note the difference. "help,,," would only be changed to "help,,"

Answer (score 1):

That thing is a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), also known as *regex* or *regexp*. It is a way to "match" strings using some rules. If you want to learn how to use it in JavaScript, read the [Mozilla Developer Network page about RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

By the way, regular expressions are also available on most languages and in some tools. It is a very useful thing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

That's a regular expression that finds a comma at the end of a string.  That code removes the comma.

Answer (score 0):

`//` defines a [JavaScript regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), used to match a pattern within a string.
`\,$` is the pattern

In this case `\,` translates to `,`.  A backslash is used to escape special characters, but in this case, it's not necessary.  An example where it would be necessary would be to remove trailing periods.  If you tried to do that with `/.$/` the period here has a different meaning; it is used as a wildcard to match [almost] any character (aside for some newlines).  So in this case to match on "." (period character) you would have to escape the wildcard (`/\.$/`).

When `$` is placed at the end of the pattern, it means only look at the end of the string.  This means that you can't mistakingly find a comma anywhere in the middle of the string (e.g., not after *help* in `help, me,`), only at the end (trailing).  It also speeds of the regular expression search considerably.  If you wanted to match on characters only at the beginning of the string, you would start off the pattern with a carat (`^`), for instance `/^,/` would find a comma at the start of a string if one existed.

It's also important to note that you're only removing one comma, whereas if you use the plus (`+`) after the comma, you'd be replacing one or more: `/,+$/`.

- Without the `+`; `trailing commas,,` becomes `trailing commas,`
- With the `+`; `no trailing comma,,` becomes `no trailing comma`

---

Comment: > With the `+`; `no trailing commas,,` becomes `no trailing comma*s*`. 

Geez, this thread's got a problem with the plural of comma